# Missing Rows In Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, magento2.2.6, order-grid

I have an interesting issue.

Admin sales **order grid** does not show all records in `sales_order_grid` table.

I tried several solutions.

For example, I activated **async grid generation** on admin panel, than I **truncated** the **table** and **cron run command filled the table** but nothing changed.

I searched several times to find similar issues but I have found nothing.

By the way, missing orders created manually, so I checked all sales tables to find any difference between the other orders. No differences :/ But it must be, right?

**Magento version is EE 2.2.6**

I hope I can find anybody to be faced this issue before or at least any idea could help. Thanks for sharing your opinions.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? If so, an answer to your own question would help others here.